# While Loop to Setup CasperJS "then()" Steps

Tags: javascript, while-loop, casperjs, phantomcss

I'm trying to test the visual state of a number of buttons -- hover, click, focus -- and was looking for a way to not copy basically the same `casper.then()` command over and over. I thought I should be able to do this in a simple loop.

I made a small array of the (currently) 5 buttons and while-looped through them adding CasperJS steps for each of the states I'd like to record. Unfortunately, only the last of the steps is actually performed.

I've read a number of posts about looping, but they all seem to involve clicking links on a page or some other scenario that doesn't seem to match what I'm looking for.

Maybe I'm just being dense? Code below...

```
casper.thenOpen( 'docs/buttons/test.html' );

var buttonStyles = [
    { selector: '.grey0', title: 'Button - Grey 0' },
    { selector: '.grey25', title: 'Button - Grey 25' },
    { selector: '.grey50', title: 'Button - Grey 50' },
    { selector: '.grey75', title: 'Button - Grey 75' },
    { selector: '.grey100', title: 'Button - Grey 100' },
];

while (buttonStyles.length > 0) {

    buttonStyle = buttonStyles.pop();

    casper.then(function(){
        phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title);
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        this.mouse.move(buttonStyle.selector);
        phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title + ' - Hover');
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        this.mouse.down(buttonStyle.selector);
        phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title + ' - Down');
    });
}

casper.test.done();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `buttonStyle` is a global variable. When you iterate over the `buttonStyles` array all 5 * 3 = 15 `then` blocks are scheduled, but since `buttonStyle` is the same reference inside of every `then` block only the last `buttonStyle` is actually checked 5 times.

Javascript doesn't have block level scope (inside while), but only function level scope. The solution would be to introduce a function to do this. You can use an IIFE or `casper.repeat` like [you did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597428/1816580).

```
while (buttonStyles.length > 0) {
    buttonStyle = buttonStyles.pop();
    (function(buttonStyle){
        casper.then(function(){
            phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title);
        });

        casper.then(function(){
            this.mouse.move(buttonStyle.selector);
            phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title + ' - Hover');
        });

        casper.then(function(){
            this.mouse.down(buttonStyle.selector);
            phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title + ' - Down');
        });
    })(buttonStyle);
}
```

Comment: Extremely useful answer in a lot of various cases

Answer (score -1):

If I didn't see a number of other posts asking similar questions, I would have just deleted this. Instead, I'll post my 8-minute-later learnings here. I wonder why I can't come up with this before posting to SO?

The appropriately named "casper.repeat" did the trick for me:

```
casper.thenOpen( 'docs/buttons/test.html' );

var buttonStyles = [
    { selector: '.grey0', title: 'Button - Grey 0' },
    { selector: '.grey25', title: 'Button - Grey 25' },
    { selector: '.grey50', title: 'Button - Grey 50' },
    { selector: '.grey75', title: 'Button - Grey 75' },
    { selector: '.grey100', title: 'Button - Grey 100' },
];

var curIndex = 0;

casper.repeat(buttonStyles.length, function() {
    buttonStyle = buttonStyles[curIndex];
    casper.then(function(){
        phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title);
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        this.mouse.move(buttonStyle.selector);
        phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title + ' - Hover');
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        this.mouse.down(buttonStyle.selector);
        phantomcss.screenshot(buttonStyle.selector, buttonStyle.title + ' - Down');
    });
    curIndex++;
});

casper.test.done();
```

Comment: Putting your `capser.then()` function(s) inside `capser.repeat()` does not work.